# Remove numbering from Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

In my document on Overleaf, chapters should have a numbering. That's working fine so far. Sadly, after I adjusted the numbering of chapters the table of contents, list of figures, etc. all got a "0" as numbering, which looks really out of place.

For example the table of contents ("Inhaltsverzeichnis") looks like this:

[image: ToC]

Same goes for the list of figures and list of tables on their corresponding pages.

How can I remove / hide the numbering for those? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome, what you show is not the default behaviour. So something you added is causing that change. We need to see a [minimal working example](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses). Having a screenshot is like asking a mechanic hy the car isn't working by showing a picture on your smartphone.

Comment: The chapters did not have a numbering in the first place. A colleague added the following to the preamble:     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large \thechapter \ }     after adding that the ToC etc got the leading zeros.

Comment: See, you already know what is causing the behaviour. Remove it and the leading zeros are gone.

Comment: Removing it will also remove the numbers for chapters as well, so e.g. the chapter "Problem" from the screenshot will not show a 1 anymore.

Comment: As well, this is not default, so womething is clearly going on. We need to see what you are doing (minimal working example, link above) to help you. We don't have psychic powers.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your problem with that, it is just a bit hard for me to describe. Anyways, we just figured out that the command was placed a little bit too early in the file, therefore including the toc etc. in the numbering as well. Though, thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Does that mean we can close this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has agreed that it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `\titleformat` command is not used the right way.
It should be

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
```

See also https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Sections_and_chapters